# Can I prevent features from being created outside an OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers-2, features

In our app, we allow users to create features on maps. The boundaries of these features will later be converted into real-life latitude/longitude coordinates, but does not make sense if features are created outside the actual boundaries of the map.

[image]

In the above screenshot, I'd like to prevent the blue feature from being drawn so that its upper edge stays *inside* the actual map.

How could I do that? I couldn't find any reference to this in OpenLayers examples or documentation.

(Currently on 2.12-rc1)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an intersect check as Aragon specifies, combined with your own polygon handler, i've modified a polygon handler that won't let the user finish drawinf if the polygon is self-intersecting:

```
var myhandler = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {

    addPoint: function(pixel) {
        var intersect = checkIntersect(this.polygon.geometry);
        if(intersect && this.polygon.geometry.components.length ==1){       
            //do nothing
        }
        else {
            OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon.prototype.addPoint.apply(this, arguments);
            if(intersect){
                this.undo();
            }
        }

    },
});
```

where the checkIntersect function checks self intersection

if you replace the checkIntersect with a function that checks for intersection with your area bounds, this should work.

use a normal DrawFeatureControl, but with your "myhandler" handler instead of a OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon

**EDIT:**
edited with better implementation

For lines, you could try and subclass the Path handler in a similar way

Comment: Oh, that looks interesting. So `this.undo();` will undo the last step in the polygon that would have been outside the boundaries? I have `drawFeature` enabled for rectangles and lines as well — is there a way to use this custom handler for all of these types without having to copy/paste it?

Comment: what this handler does is override the finishGeometry function of the Polygon handler. If the geometry that is drawn is intersecting, it undoes the last point added to the geometry. One major drawback is that this will only trigger on the last point added, and thus only undo this.. So, actually a bad solution. Let me try to rewrite it...

Comment: Feel free to replace the answer's content rather than "appending" the right one. I'll try and see if I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an extent for your map object in openlayers, so user won't be able to browse and draw feature outside the extent.

restrictedExtent will limit user to these extents, take a look at the sample

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds
(
    2819215.11322, 4234728.55108, 5081316.11322, 5269161.55108
);

var options = 
{
    maxExtent: bounds,
    numZoomLevels: 10,
    restrictedExtent: bounds,
    projection: "EPSG:3857",
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(
        {dragPanOptions: {enableKinetic: true}}
    ),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ]

};
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_div',options);
```

Comment: This works, but only if the map is zoomed in close enough. Once I zoom out, I can still [draw outside](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MROZz.png) – what gives? How could I stop people from zooming out too much?

Comment: you can use maxResolution and numZoomLevels options to prevent user zooming out too much
take a look at http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html

mess around with maxResolution value and you will find a optimum number or use 'auto'

Comment: Hm, this seems to be more complicated since my map is a Zoomify tileset. I have to set `maxResolution: Math.pow(2, this.baseLayer.numberOfTiers-1)` and `numZoomLevels: this.baseLayer.numberOfTiers+1` – everything else results in a wrong display.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is that using openlayers intersection method to check if feature intersect with your map extent feature...

you can check out example [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/intersects.html)...

I will add a small example here if I can find time to write the code.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: But even then, what if the feature *does* intersect? It'd be annoying for the user to get an error message, having to draw the feature again.

Comment: @atlefren has said what i meant.