# OpenLayers - vector boxes and paths

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

I'm using OpenLayers to make warehouse map.
How to prevent drawing lines (paths) over some vector objects already on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this question which is similar to yours, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/26445/3071)...

i have given an answer too.

i hope it helps you...